# Matrix norm inequality proof of $||A^{-1}-B^{-1}||$

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Proof that if A is invertible and $||A-B|| < ||A^{-1}||^{-1}$
then
$||A^{-1}-B^{-1}||$ $\leq$ $||A^{-1}||\frac{||I-A^{-1}B||}{1-||I-A^{-1}B||}$

I have tried substuting in $||A^{-1}-B^{-1}|| = B^{-1}(B-A)A^{-1}$
and chaging $||I-A^{-1}B||$ to $||A^{-1}||||A-B||\leq I $from the given condition, but I cant get final inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $B$ is invertible from $A$ invertible and $\lVert A-B\rVert\leq\lVert A^{-1}\rVert^{-1}$.  If $A=B$ there is nothing to prove, so assume $A\neq B$.

From $A^{-1}-B^{-1}=(I-B^{-1}A)A^{-1}$, you have $\lVert A^{-1}-B^{-1}\rVert\leq\lVert A^{-1}\rVert\cdot\lVert I-B^{-1}A\rVert$.  Now we want:
$$
\lVert I-B^{-1}A\rVert\leq\frac{\lVert I-A^{-1}B\rVert}{1-\lVert I-A^{-1}B\rVert}
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\lVert I-B^{-1}A\rVert\leq\lVert I-A^{-1}B\rVert+\lVert I-A^{-1}B\rVert\lVert I-B^{-1}A\rVert
$$
which follows from
$$
I-B^{-1}A=(I-A^{-1}B)(I-B^{-1}A)-(I-A^{-1}B).
$$