# Estimating $\|B^{-1}-A^{-1} \|$ for regular matrices $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $\| \cdot  \|$ be a submultiplicative matrix norm. Let $A$ and $B$ be ivertible matrices and assume that $$\|B-A\| < \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}.$$
>
> Prove that: $$\|B^{-1}-A^{-1} \|  \le \frac{\|B-A\|}{1- \|A^{-1}\| \cdot \|B-A\|} \| A^{-1} \|^2$$

My attempt goes like this:

By assumption we have that $0 \le \|B-A\||A^{-1}\| < 1$, so we get

$$ \|B-A\| \| A^{-1} \|^2 \le \frac{\|B-A\|}{1- \|A^{-1}\| \cdot \|B-A\|} \| A^{-1} \|^2$$

Here we should probably use the submultiplicativity, so

$$\|(B-A)A^{-2}\| \le \|B-A\| \| A^{-1} \|^2 $$

I tried to multiply this out but I get nothing of worth. However I found the identity $B = A(I-A^{-1}(A-B))$, could I use that here somewhere?

Comment: This follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985504/matrix-norm-inequality-proof-of-a-1-b-1